# Migrated to new php, now get, Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in blog editor

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, offset

I recently migrated hosts for my website which came with a newer version of php. Since the migration I have been getting the error `Warning: Trying to access array offset on the value of type bool in /xxx/edit-post.php on line 150` which relates to `if($row3['catID'] == $row2['catID']){` appearing between each checkbox of what is the blogpost category selection field. It does not appear to impede the function of selecting categories for the blog post.

```
    <legend>Categories</legend>

    <?php

    $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle');
    while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){

        $stmt3 = $db->prepare('SELECT catID FROM blog_post_cats WHERE catID = :catID AND postID = :postID') ;
        $stmt3->execute(array(':catID' => $row2['catID'], ':postID' => $row['postID']));
        $row3 = $stmt3->fetch(); 

        if($row3['catID'] == $row2['catID']){
            $checked = 'checked=checked';
        } else {
            $checked = null;
        }

        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
    }

    ?>
```

The above is the relevant section of the code from the edit-post page. I have attempted several solutions, but I truly do not understand what I am doing, the blog itself was a very simple install (even simpler than phpbb), so before I migrated I never had to contend with more than HTML, CSS, and js. What do I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Appears something is going on with $row3 or $row2 that makes it a boolean (true or false) now whereas it's not an array. Very difficult to come up with a solution that won't break something without seeing EVERY iteration or instance of it used in the entirety of the framework.. though to fix it a simple if check for $row3 and $row2 if ( !is_array ) { $var = array(); } or better yet if ( isset( $row3['catID'] ) before each comparison might do the trick... again, hard to say if this is recommended without seeing every use of the variables to make sure nothing unexpected or dangerous occurs...

Comment: If you check under "Return value" in the [manual for PDOStatement::fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), you can see that it says: _"The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. **In all cases, false is returned on failure or if there are no more rows.**"_. So check if there are any rows before assuming there are. I would also recommend you to look into using SQL Joins, which would allow you to fetch all records in a single query (instead of making new queries in a loop)

Answer (score -1):

It would appear either `$row2` or `$row3` is being converted to a boolean (true or false) value by some mechanism in the framework elsewhere. I would recommend searching for every instance or use of `$row2` or `$row3` in the entire framework to find out specifically what's happening. If this is due to an update or change in PHP versions, it's reasonable to assume something else, perhaps more crucial, could be broken as well.

If you can confirm this is a lone, insignificant issue (sometimes `$row2` will be an array as expected, sometimes a boolean and of no consequence elsewhere), something like this should work:

Replace
`if($row3['catID'] == $row2['catID']){`

With
`if( is_array( $row3 ) && isset( $row3['catID'] && is_array( $row2 ) && isset( $row2['catID'] && $row3['catID'] == $row2['catID']){`

What does this is basically check if each variable is in fact an array, then checks if each specific array key exists BEFORE the comparison.

There are a few others ways to do the same thing, such as simply checking if `$row3['catID']` has been declared using `isset`, etc.

Again, please remember this is a cheap fix. You should discover exactly why this is happening by going through every line of code that uses and of course declares `$row2` and `$row3` to make sure whatever is causing this problem isn't or won't cause something dangerous that might not trigger a warning.